# Code that is supposed to solve Laplace's equation iteratively - numbers stored in array change unexpectedly to random large numbers

Tags: c

I've written a program in C that iteratively solves Laplace's equation on a square domain by successive over-relaxation, but although it was working perfectly a few days ago, I've come back to it and now it's doing really weird things.
The program involves creating two 7x7 arrays, one to hold the values of phi (the dependent variable in Laplace's equation) and one to hold the residuals from the successive over-relaxation. The array of residuals is filled with zeroes initially because I thought that was probably a good idea, but thinking about it now it shouldn't make much difference either way.
The problem is that certain values in the array (specifically R[4][6]) jump around randomly to enormous numbers, even though I've set them to zero and then not touched them. I know this because I put another line in to output the value of the residual at (4,6) to the screen after each iteration. This problem is causing my method of checking for convergence to fail, and also somehow causing the final solution (plotted as a surface using gnuplot) to look correct except for small peaks and valleys in the surface.
I'm coding in C, Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2 is the compiler I'm using (the files are definitely saved as C files and not C++ ones too), outputting the data into a DATA file which comes up in notepad when opened, and finally using gnuplot to produce the 3D contour plots that are my results. I'm working on windows 7.
I've put the code here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8220425 and you need to enter 1.35 for alpha when the program asks you for it.
If anyone could help at all I would be very grateful!

Comment: Could you clarify you question, please? What are you actually asking? Could you please provide code snippets, examples where it does and does not work. Please see this check list of what to include: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx

Comment: *certain values in the array ... jump around randomly to enormous numbers* - sounds like uninitialized values, either being written there or you are going beyond array bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf("Residual at (4,6)=%lf\n",R[4,6]);
```

You mean:

```
printf("Residual at (4,6)=%lf\n",R[4][6]);
```

The issue here is that `R[4,6]` basically means `R[6]` (`4,6` means: evaluate `4`, then evaluate `6`), which is some sort of pointer rather than a double. So it will print random-looking values depending on where your array has been allocated in memory.